# What is the purpose of an Arduino?

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi

What can an Arduino do that a Raspberry Pi can't?

Comment: Why do we have small cars when we could all be driving trucks or suvs?  What is the purpose of anything smaller than an SUV?

Comment: an arduino can run off of a battery for a significantly longer amount of time.

Comment: it costs less, the arduino branded items and even some clones are grossly overpriced.  you are dealling with an mcu that costs about 10 times less than the pi processor and other support the pi needs to be functionally equivalent.

Comment: What can a raspberry pi do that my laptop/desktop cant?  What is the purpose of a raspberry pi?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to software or programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arduino is a microprocessor, not a computer. It means that Arduino has inputs and outputs that you can connect to different electronic components such as motors, lights, sensors, etc.

Those inputs and outputs are only pins that you can send or receive a certain amount current.

Arduino has a pretty limited memory so you can only store a simple program on it, not a OS. It is mostly used in automation. For example you want to automate a garden so you have sensors to detect the amount of water in the ground and then use this information to enable a motor that will turn the water on. There is a complete API to simplify the coding between the programmer and the device.

For example, you have a function that will control the speed of the motor in rpm so you only have to give the speed as a parameter of that function.

Raspberry pi is a complete computer, so you can plug a screen, mouse, keyboard to it. There is some OS available for it. It is not just only pins as inputs or outputs, but HDMI input or usb port.

So Raspberry pi and Arduino are completely different and have both a different field of interest.

You will not order a Raspberry Pi to automate the temperature of your coffee as you will not use a Arduino to make a OS.

I hope this will help making the difference between the two.

Good luck!

Comment: sadly because the prices have crossed over (a pi zero costs less than an arduino) and they both can check the temp of your coffee maker (or take a picture to see how much coffee is there without walking over to check) questions like this will continue.  Point being, many folks will buy a pi to take simple measurements, make a simple clock, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the functions and capabilities of the Pi Zero and the Arduino boards have started to overlap, as have the prices (although where I live the Pi Zeros are still somewhat more expensive that Arduinos). Perhaps we will see the applications start to overlap, too.

Conventionally, the Pi has been used in situations that demanded, or at least benefited from, running a full operating system, while the Arduino was more for running a single, custom program. I don't think there's been much interest in running code on a Pi that does not run under an OS, but it seems to be possible, up to a point. I'm not whether all the hardware is accessible this way, because some of it requires proprietary drivers, IIRC.

Because the Pi conventionally runs a full Linux kernel and utilities, it's been slower to start up in embedded applications, whereas the Arduinos essentially boot right into application code. The Pis have slightly greater power consumption (quite a bit greater, with the full-size models), and are a bit larger.

I suspect that, if you were planning commercial production, basing something around Arduino-type hardware is more likely to be productive that using a Pi. I have come across Pis being used for commercial products, but not (I think) for mass-market applications. The hardware and programming style of an Arduino is much closer to the kind of thing that you can miniaturize into a consumer product, even though the Arduino itself may be comparatively expensive.

In short, I would expect that for casual, home, and research use, it's increasingly easy to justify using a Pi Zero over any kind of microcontroller; but if I had to prototype a mass-market item, Arduino would still be closer to the final hardware spec.